# C format specifier "%n" in Java

Tags: java, c, printf

so I'm starting to learn java and I was wondering if I could use the "%n" parameter (from C printf()), which should write the number of bytes written up to the "%n" parameter:

this is it's use in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int val;

  printf("ciao %n ciao\n", &val);

  printf("val = %d\n", val);

  return 0;

}
```

prints:

```
ciao  ciao
val = 5
```

But when I try to use it in java:

```
public class CharTest
{ 
   public static void main(String[] argv)
   {    
      int  value;

      System.out.printf("\nNumber of bytes written up to now: %n\n", &value); 
      System.out.println(value);
   }
}
```

The java compiler gives me this message:

```
CharTest.java:20: error: illegal start of expression

System.out.printf("\nNumber of bytes written up to now: %n\n", &value); 
                                                               ^
1 error
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: The [Formatter documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#summary) would have answered your question.

Comment: It really shouldn't be in C at all because it's such an easy attack vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C you can pass parameters by reference or change the value of variables passed to functions by passing a pointer to them, the `%n` specifier stores the number of characters written so far in `value` and in order to do that you had to pass the pointer to `value` with `&value`.

In Java it's not possible to pass parameters by reference or to pass pointers of variables and the same syntax is not possible, `&` operator is bitwise and. The `printf` `%n` specifier in Java prints a platform specific line separator.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It's possible with a one member array of `int` but I think this is out of scope for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in Java at all. There is no conversion that would correspond to `%n` of the `printf` C. Instead, you can use the [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) to format the string

```
String s = String.format("\nNumber of *%s* written up to now: ", "characters");
```

then check the number of characters in `s`, and format that separately:

```
int len = s.length()
String result = String.format("%s%d\n", s, len);
```

Lastly, do note that unlike in C where `char` is exact synonym of `byte`, in Java the strings do not even consist of bytes, but Unicode/UTF-16 codepoints. Asking how many bytes are written by a string formatting operation is meaningless.